# Why is the first for-loop decrementing?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, for-loop, bubble-sort

As I am trying to understand the concept of Bubblesort, I stumbled over this piece of code which is confusing me. Why is the first foor loop decrementing? Why isn't it `for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {}` ?

```
void bubblesort(int arr[], int len){
    int k=0; //Tauschvariable
    // Elemente, von rechts beginnend
    for (int i=len; i>0; i--) {
        // Läuft das array nach links ab
        for (int j=0; j<len-1;j++){
            // vergleich zweier
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]){
            k = arr[j];
            arr[j+1]=k;
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because each iteration of the inner loop bubbles up the highest element from the unsorted part of the array to `arr[len-1], arr[len-2],...` .

Comment: Why don't you try to reverse it and compare the results?

Comment: This code doesn't work does it? The code that swaps `arr[j]` and `arr[j+1]` looks incorrect to me. And usually the `j` loop would go from `0` to `i-2` rather than to the end of the array each time.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter, it works both ways. If you look carefully, `i` isn't used anywhere else. I guess the author wanted to make it this way for some reason.

Comment: Usually the `j` loop would be `for (int j = 0; j < i-1; j++)`.

Comment: @PaulHankin - Yeah, that's one possible optimization. Another one would be to just note the biggest value while iterating and perform only a single swap at the end.

Answer (score 0):

it just bound the max number of passes to size of array `O(n^2)` **by decrementing and testing against zero** some compilers might take advantage of used CPU  architecture and use Zero flag instead additional cmp instruction that would be needed if comparing agains any other value than `0`.

For example `;i<n;i++)` can be translated to:

```
inc i
cmp i,n
jc ???
```

And `;i>0;i--)` can be translated to:

```
dec i
jnz ???
```

As usual (for any bubble sort I see on this site) your Bubble sort implementation is missing the stop condition so it does not iterate once the array is sorted making it very slow (always go through `n^2` iterations).

I am more used to bubble sorts like this (C++):

```cpp
template <class T> void sort_asc_bubble(T *a,int n)
    {
    int i,e; T a0,a1;
    for (e=1;e;n--)                                     // loop until no swap occurs
     for (e=0,a0=a[0],a1=a[1],i=1;i<n;a0=a1,i++,a1=a[i])// proces unsorted part of array
      if (a0>a1)                                        // condition if swap needed
      { a[i-1]=a1; a[i]=a0; a1=a0; e=1; }               // swap and allow to process array again
    }
template <class T> void sort_dsc_bubble(T *a,int n)
    {
    int i,e; T a0,a1;
    for (e=1;e;n--)                                     // loop until no swap occurs
     for (e=0,a0=a[0],a1=a[1],i=1;i<n;a0=a1,i++,a1=a[i])// proces unsorted part of array
      if (a0<a1)                                        // condition if swap needed
      { a[i-1]=a1; a[i]=a0; a1=a0; e=1; }               // swap and allow to process array again
    }
```

sorry its in C++ but if you get rid of the template and exchange the T with used data type you got C again. Something like this (just rewritten in answer editor so its not tested):

```
#define T int
void sort_asc_bubble(T *a,int n)
    {
    int i,e; T a0,a1;
    for (e=1;e;n--)                                     // loop until no swap occurs
     for (e=0,a0=a[0],a1=a[1],i=1;i<n;a0=a1,i++,a1=a[i])// proces unsorted part of array
      if (a0>a1)                                        // condition if swap needed
      { a[i-1]=a1; a[i]=a0; a1=a0; e=1; }               // swap and allow to process array again
    }
void sort_dsc_bubble(T *a,int n)
    {
    int i,e; T a0,a1;
    for (e=1;e;n--)                                     // loop until no swap occurs
     for (e=0,a0=a[0],a1=a[1],i=1;i<n;a0=a1,i++,a1=a[i])// proces unsorted part of array
      if (a0<a1)                                        // condition if swap needed
      { a[i-1]=a1; a[i]=a0; a1=a0; e=1; }               // swap and allow to process array again
    }
```

Pay attention to the `e` variable ... so if any swap occurred its true so if its false after the nested for loop is done stop ... This will make your bubble sort much much faster on average.